# Converting mutable to immutable map

Tags: scala, immutability, mutable, scala-collections

```
private[this]object MMMap extends  HashMap[A, Set[B]] with MultiMap[A, B]
```

How convert it to immutable?

Comment: I *guess* you create a new one? Just guessing, but usually things work this way.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean

Comment: hmm.. `MMMap.toMap` ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The immutable hierarchy doesn't contain a MultiMap, so you won't be able to use the converted structure with the same convenient syntax.  But if you're happy to deal with key/valueset pairs, then:

If you just want a mutable `HashMap`, you can just use `x.toMap` in 2.8 or `collection.immutable.Map(x.toList: _*)` in 2.7.

But if you want the whole structure to be immutable--including the underlying set!--then you have to do more: you need to convert the sets along the way.  In 2.8:

```
x.map(kv => (kv._1,kv._2.toSet)).toMap
```

In 2.7:

```
collection.immutable.Map(
  x.map(kv => (kv._1,collection.immutable.Set(kv._2.toList: _*))).toList: _*
)
```

Answer (score 34):

```
scala> val mutableMap = new HashMap[Int, String]
mutableMap: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map()

scala> mutableMap += 1 -> "a"
res5: mutableMap.type = Map((1,a))

scala> mutableMap
res6: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map((1,a))

scala> val immutableMap = mutableMap.toMap
immutableMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map((1,a))

scala> immutableMap += 2 -> "b"
<console>:11: error: reassignment to val
       immutableMap += 2 -> "b"
                ^
```

Comment: I was surprised a bit when I saw "mutableMap.toMap" but then I verified api and didn't found nothing resembling.
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.html
Second issue  - Set[B] is mutable. That is why converting is not so easy.

Comment: @Jeriho: toMap is introduced in Scala2.8

Comment: Thx Eastsun. Sorry Jeriho, I didn't mentioned it.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `myMap.toMap` to convert an a mutable map into immutable in Scala 2.8 and later versions.

Looking at definition of `toMap` from documentation:

```
def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U] = {
  val b = immutable.Map.newBuilder[T, U]
  for (x <- self) b += x
  b.result
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can just to the following

```
val imm_map = MMMap.toMap
```

Comment: This leaves the `Set` mutable; you can't mutate the resulting `Map`, but you can modify the `Set`