# A function to convert java map to scala map

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, maps, scala-java-interop

Totally new to scala so any help is appreciated. I'm trying to pass objects from python to scala via the JVM, so I need a function that takes a java map as an input and returns a scala map as output.

I'm not really sure yet if I want the map to be mutable or immutable, but I've played around with using .asScala.toMap to make it immutable, but that threw an error. I think the issues is with the syntax of my function?

```scala
private object PythonUtils {

  def toScalaMap[K, V](jm: java.util.Map[K, V]): Map[K, V] = {
    jm.asScala
  }

}
```

From what I've got so far, the function does a type check on the parameters and then takes java map and converts it to scala. However, when I compile this I'm getting a `type mismatch` error `found: scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V] required java.util.Map[K,V]` Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable

def toScalaMutableMap[K, V](jm: java.util.Map[K, V]): mutable.Map[K, V] = {
  jm.asScala
}

def toScalaImmutableMap[K, V](jm: java.util.Map[K, V]): Map[K, V] = {
  jm.asScala.toMap
}
```

`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.9.0"`

[Convert Java Map to Scala Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918956/convert-java-map-to-scala-map)

[Converting mutable to immutable map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817055/converting-mutable-to-immutable-map)

> However, when I compile this I'm getting a type mismatch error `found: scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V] required java.util.Map[K,V]`

Look what line produces this error.

Maybe you have `import java.util.Map`. Then `Map` refers to `java.util.Map`. If you remove this import then `Map` will refer to `scala.Predef.Map` aka `scala.immutable.Map`.