# How to convert scala.collection.mutable.Map to scala.collection.immutable.Map in Kotlin?

Tags: scala, kotlin

A Scala library, I'm using in my Kotlin code, provides a function, which expects a `scala.collection.immutable.Map<String!, String!>!` as an argument.

To have a minimal example, let's call this function `f`. I'd like to the values of a given Kotlin map to it, but I'm struggling with the conversion:

```kotlin
fun f(x: scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, String>) {}

fun main() {
    val m = mapOf("foo" to "bar")
    val m2 = scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.MapHasAsScala(m).asScala()
    f(m2)
}
```

Error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, String>
Found:
scala.collection.mutable.Map<String!, String!>!
```

I understand, [I should use `.toMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819674/1866775), but I'm not allowed to call this function without providing an `ev` argument:

```kotlin
val m2 = scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.MapHasAsScala(m).asScala().toMap<String, String>()
```

Error:

```
No value passed for parameter 'ev'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using `scala.collection.immutable.Map.from` and put it into an extension function. :)

```kotlin
fun <A, B> Map<A, B>.toImmutableScalaMap(): scala.collection.immutable.Map<A, B> =
    scala.collection.immutable.Map.from(scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.MapHasAsScala(this).asScala())

fun main() {
    val m = mapOf("foo" to "bar")
    f(m.toImmutableScalaMap())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that `ev` parameter is an implicit evidence, that indicates the generic type in the iterable object "namely `A`" is a subtype of `(String, String)`. This can be figured out by the compiler in scala, without need to passing argument for it (it is implicit). so in Scala this works:

```scala
val myMap = ... //of type scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]
val immutableMap = myMap.toMap // scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, String]
```

But using this in Kotlin or Java needs passing an instance of type `<:<[(String, String), (String, String)]` (meaning a tuple of 2 strings, is a subtype of tuple of 2 strings, which is actually true). I don't think that you can want to do this, you also cannot, because of illegal inheritance. I have 2 recommendations.

**1st**:
Create a Scala object, which can easily do this for you

```scala
object MapConvertor {
  def mutableToImmutable[K, V](mutableMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[K, V]) = mutableMap.toMap
}
```

And just call this inside your Kotlin file (like `MapConvertor.mutableToImmutable(...)`), they are binary compatible, there would be no problems.

**2nd**
Map in Scala, also mixes in IterableOnce trait (implements IterableOnce interface, this is more Java-ish :D). so you can cast it to the supertype. Map also has a static method that can create the map from IterableOnce. So:

```java
scala.collection.IterableOnce<scala.Tuple2<String, String>> immutableMapIterable;
immutableMapIterable = (scala.collection.IterableOnce<scala.Tuple2<String, String>>) Test.m();
return scala.collection.immutable.Map.from(immutableMapIterable);
```